# VBA Loop to copy and paste data from nth column to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop that takes data from Workbook1.Worksheet1, column M, starting in row 9 to 700 and pastes it into Workbook2.Worksheet2 starting on cell F8. After that it will grab the next row from Workbook1 (column N) and paste it into Workbook2 8 columns later (cell N8). And it repeats 24 times to grab all rows from Workbook1.

```
Sub importdata()

Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer
J = 6
K = 13
Wrksht1 As Range
Wrksht2 As Range
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsb")

    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Worksheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Worksheet2")

For I = 1 To 24
    Set Wrksht2 = ws2.Range(K & 9)
    Set Wrksht1 = ws1.Range(J & 8)
        Wrksht1 = Wrksht2
        J = J + 8
        K = K + 1
Next I

End Sub
```

This is my current code right now, I have the loop working so it should place the values in the right spot of workbook2 but I can't get the loop to grab the values from the row in workbook1 and paste the values in the directed spots.

Comment: Try Wrksht1.value =WrkSht2.value

Comment: But in reality it would be much better reading the range into a VBA array and then pasting the array.  This would be two operations rather than 48 for each row.

Comment: You might also wish to install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the Code Inspections.  You will learn a lot about how to write formally correct and robust VBA code.

Comment: In which of the workbooks is the code? 1, 2, or 3? Could you confirm that you want to copy `1!M9:M700` to `2!N8:N699` and `1!N9:N32` (or `1!N701:N724`) to `2!N8:N31`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Sub CopyRowsToDifferentColumns()
    
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Dim destRange As Range
    
    Dim sourceCols As Long
    Dim destCols As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set source workbook, worksheet, and range
    Set sourceWB = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets("Worksheet1")
    Set sourceRange = sourceWS.Range("M9:AJ700") '24 columns
    sourceCols = sourceRange.Columns.Count

    ' Set destination workbook, worksheet, and range
    Set destWB = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsb")
    Set destWS = destWB.Worksheets("Worksheet2")
    Set destRange = destWS.Range("F8")
    destCols = sourceCols * 8
    
    ' Loop through each column of the source range and paste it in a different column in the destination range
    For i = 1 To sourceCols
        sourceRange.Columns(i).Copy
        destRange.Offset(0, (i - 1) * 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i
    
    ' Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just made a couple small adjustments and it worked!